# XmlException when adding an XML string as a value in an XML SOAP request body

Tags: c#, xml, soap, opc

I am writing an application that utilizes XML SOAP. The code that writes the request is unfortunately out of my hands, as it is a DLL file that was only given to me. I downloaded Jetbrain's dotPeek to decompile the DLL file and look at the code, there I found out that the soap message request body is being written as such

```
string message = "<Value>" + myValue + "</Value>";
```

and then parsed as an XElement afterwards.

Now this works most of the time, as most requests accept normal values (eg. `<Value>true</Value>`). But there's a specific protocol in the xml technology we are working on wherein we have to pass entire xml strings as a value like so

```
string myValue = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><Foobar ID=\"123\" />";
```

This throws an error:

> Unexpected XML declaration. The XML declaration must be the first node
>   in the document, and no white space characters are allowed to appear
>   before it.

As my resulting xml body would look like:

```
<Value><?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Foobar ID="123" /></Value>
```

Is it possible for me to somehow pass this xml string while avoiding the error? I am writing all this in C#. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found an answer after a couple hours. The quickest solution would be to convert the start and end tags to [character entities](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/xml/xml_character_entities.htm)

```
string myValue = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><Foobar ID=\"123\" />";
myValue = myValue.Replace("<", "&lt;").Replace(">", "&gt;");
```

You can also opt to use

- HttpUtility.HtmlEncode
- System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlEncode